# DokuWiki Search very slow after upgrade

Tags: php, apache-2.4

I've upgraded my dokuwiki version on Ubuntu 14.04 "Detritus" to "Release 2018-04-22a "Greebo"" recently.

During the upgrade, I also had to upgrade PHP version to "5.6.36-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1"(previously 5.5).

The only problem I have left after the upgrade is that the search is VERY slow: It takes about 15-45 seconds to bring search results, before the upgrade, this was instantaneous . The wiki is also quite small, around 1000 pages.

I've tried rebuilding the index but that doesn't seem to change anything. Disabling addons one by one also didn't help (I thought maybe it was a plugin that slows things down)

What I also noticed is that an Apache process reaches 100% CPU for as long as the search runs and ends right after the results are displayed. I'm suspecting it's the PHP upgrade that is causing CPU spike but I can't pinpoint what's the issue.

Can someone point me in what I should be investigating?

Apache 2.4 VirtualHost Config:

```
ServerAdmin it@xyz.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/DokuWiki/public_html/
    ServerName wiki.xyz.com
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

PHP.ini

```
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 17
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 512M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 200M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 200M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
mail.add_x_header = On
sql.safe_mode = Off
bcmath.scale = 0

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]

[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
```

Comment: Please add information on: (1) why did you upgrade php? (i'm guessing the new version of dokuwiki required it) (2) how did you upgrade php? (3) how did you upgrade dokuwiki? (4) did you upgrade any other packages? (5) you tagged the question with apache-2.2, but ubuntu 14.04 includes apache 2.4, is this a mistake? or did you downgrade apache? (6) paste the configuration for the apache virtualhost, the php.ini for php, my.cnf for mysql and if any, the config for dokuwiki

Comment: 1) dokuwiki required an upgrade
2) "apt-get install php5.6" & "apt-get install php5.6-ldap"
3) using "dokuwiki updater plugin"
4) no
5) sorry wrong tag, it's apache 2.4
6) there is no MYSQL, dokuwiki is text based. dokuwiki also doesn't really have a single configuration file, php & apache virtual hosts are posted on original question

Comment: Could it be that the whole index is rebuilt for every search ? if so, maybe a cleanup (ie https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:maintenance ) can fix the problem (specifically cleanup for locks). If not, I would enable `verbose` mode to diagnose what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seeing your answers to my comment, I'm listing a kind of checklist:

(Re) install all the required php packages from the Odrej Sury PPA, [as recommended by him](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) and **remove the repositories or packages you added if any is different**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-compat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It should install the correct PHP versions in compatibility mode. Then re-install the module for apache2, disable the old module and enable the new one:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And I would probably upgrade Apache to use the Ondrej repo too, as recommend by him in the PHP repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Check the php versions available and the default one:

```
update-alternatives --query php
```

If php5.6 is not set as default, set it (or remove php5.5):

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize5.6
```

[Check the changelog for features and config changes](https://www.dokuwiki.org/changes), you did a BIG version jump from 2015 to 2018, particularly the ldap, gallery and ziplib changes)

Check the [recommended php.ini settings for Dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:php)

If you can, redo the [upgrade/install following the steps from the DokuWiki page](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:upgrade#upgrading_dokuwiki).

And finally, check your **virtualhost**, it should (probably) have the ***AllowOverride*** setting to ***ALL*** so the included **.htaccess** file in DokuWiki works.

ps. I forgot to ask for the error.log and access.log, it might be easy to identify the error, but redoing the steps the right way is a good idea any way.

Comment: I'll clone the VM and test. Will let you know. Thanks for the response